Is there a way to predict icon size in PWA's Splash Screen on Android?
By default Splash Screen for PWA in Android is made of the app icon, background color and app name. These elements are not customizable.
I want to to create a smooth transition between a splash screen and in-app loading animation. For that I need to predict how big will be the icon.
I can't find any resources on this. Is there a way to know how big the icon will be in the Splash Screen?

I think this can be handled with any of the bel:-
(1) Providing Optimal icons in the web app manifest.
(2) Placeholder splash in your application :- Create a custom in-app splash screen that mimics the browser’s splash screen.
(3) Fallback Approach :- If precision is critical but measurements aren't exact Try doing transition your animation from a larger generic icon that fades/scales down to the estimated size based on the screen.
This are the approaches which i thought would work, though i never tested the same, or implemented this way before.

Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't address my question
